# wso2 das event indexing delay

Tags: wso2, analytics, wso2-das, bigdata

When I send events to a stream receiver the following occurs:

- I can see the events in the data explorer
- If I try to filter the results by query, theorically matching results are not shown
- Those matching results appear after some time has passed

I suppose the issue is due to a delay in the indexing of the data. How can I get events to be indexed in real time?

Answer (score 0):

I was overriding the _timestamp parameter, but I noticed that the timestamp shown in the data explorer was "in the future"...it was a _timestamp problem!